# Refresh php code every second

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe

I have a log-in screen visible in an iframe, when someone logs-in on the iframe there should pop up a menu-button on the main page.

This is the code That I have now:

```
<?php   if (isset($player)){
                        echo'
            <ul class="nav-header pull-right">
                <li>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-image dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button">
                            <img src="assets/img/avatars/avatar10.jpg" alt="Avatar">
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                            <li class="dropdown-header">Profile</li>
                            <li>
                                <a tabindex="-1" href="base_pages_profile.html">
                                    <i class="si si-user pull-right"></i>
                                    <span class="badge badge-success pull-right"></span>Profile
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)">
                                    <i class="si si-settings pull-right"></i>Settings
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-header">Actions</li>
                            <li>
                                <a tabindex="-1" href="logout.php">
                                    <i class="si si-logout pull-right"></i>Log out
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>'; } ?>
```

isset($player) becomes true as soon as someone logs-in but this code only works if you refresh the page, how can I create something that this code refreshes as soon as someone logs in?

Comment: Why is the login box placed within an iframe? Unless there is a specific need, I would suggest just rendering it as part of the page instead of in an iframe. In that way, the page would update when the login gets submitted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use AJAX; using a technique often referred to as [**Short Polling**](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery/). What you can do is, using `setInterval`, you can fire an AJAX request every second and fetch the new code. Every second would be too much for the server to handle, so take care of it too:

```
setInterval(function () {
  $("#divId").load("/path/to/php/response.php");
}, 1000);
```

The `1000` is one second as it is measured in milliseconds.

Another technique would be to send a request to the server, that would create a request which is left open for a period of time. If updates are received during this interval, the response is sent to the client, else the connection is terminated. This technique is called [**Long Polling**](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery/). In code it would look like:

```
(function poll() {
   setTimeout(function() {
     $.ajax({ url: "server", success: function(data) {
        sales.setValue(data.value);
     }, dataType: "json", complete: poll });
   }, 30000);
})();
```

However, sometimes, hammering your server with requests every 10 seconds might not be an *great* thing to do. So, who do we call in these desperate times? **Socket Streaming**. Clients send requests to the server. The request creates an indefinite stream with the server which knows to send a response to the client in a case an update is received.

For further reading:

- [The Benefits of Web Sockets](http://www.websocket.org/quantum.html)
- [Building a Real Time Chat App using Laravel 4](https://medium.com/laravel-4/laravel-4-real-time-chat-eaa550829538#.u9sttzpgd)

Comment: Okay, i will try this, is this the exact code that I can copy into my html? I have never used ajax before.

Comment: Well, this is not the *exact* code. Please use the real `id` of the element where you wanna load the PHP's code. And also, the URL to be loaded should be changed.